# Gulp watch crashes in between if any error is found

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am writing a gulp task to browserify, compile my less files into css and to run a gulp-webserver. On Client side I am using React 0.14. The moment any error is found in browserify, my gulp watch crashes. Every time I have to stop the watch task and run it again. How to avoid this? I mean if an error is found and if i fix the error, how can i again run the browserify task without my watch getting crashed. If I get an error in browserify like: the closing JSX tag missing...and Once I fix the error, how to stop my watch from crashing.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var babelify    = require("babelify");
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var plugins     = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var watchLess   = require('gulp-watch-less');
var domain      = require("domain");

gulp.task('webserver', function(){
    gulp.src('./')
    .pipe(plugins.webserver({
      fallback   : 'index.html',
      host       : 'localhost',
      livereload : {
        enable : true
      },
      open       : true
    }))
})

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
  console.log('Browserifying ...');
    return browserify({
    entries : ['./js/index.js'],
    debug   : true
  })
  .transform('babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
  .bundle()
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
  })
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
})

gulp.task('build-css', function(){
  return gulp.src('./less/**/*.less')
    .pipe(plugins.less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
})

gulp.task('build', function() {
  runSequence(
    ['build-css'], ['browserify'], ['webserver'], ['watch']
  );
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('./js/*.js',['browserify'])
  gulp.watch('./less/**/*.less',['build-css'])
  gulp.watch('./css/**/*.css')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your error handling method:

`this.emit('end')`

Comment: Are you sure ? This is one of my gulp file and it works perfectly : https://github.com/mijamo/React-cartographer/blob/master/gulpfile.js (look at the rebundle function)

Comment: yes... once I get some error...I have to re-run the task